# Java Regular Expression to search in String

Tags: java, regex, string

How will you proceed the following string:

```
[p('WHITE'),p('GREEN'),p('GREEN','RED'),p('GREEN','YELLOW'),p('GREEN','YELLOW','RED')]
```

to get a List of Nodes as suggested in the answers.

Comment: To get a list of which strings? The values between p(' and ')? Unique or non unique?

Comment: That doesn't look like a string. Is it enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: What is the expected output that you are looking for? Can you give the exact output you want for your example that you have given.

Comment: Why should this not be a string? It is a "sequence of characters", which is often called a "string" for short.

Comment: Yes it is enclosed in double quotes. And yes to have the values between p(' and') that are unique

Comment: @Roland, ok, but when someone writes `[a, b, c]` I don't see a string, I see an array literal. Writing strings with quotes around it (especially when there are also quotes in the string) makes it clearer that it is a string.

Comment: What is the grammar for the input?  Without a grammar, we cannot know if regexes are even feasible, let alone formulate one.

Comment: @Skilldrick: When I look at `[a, b, c]` I see a lot of dark and light pixels. It all depends on how you interpret these pixels. I interpreted them just as a sequence of characters, you saw some commonly used syntax and structured the sequence of characters further as being an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how complex the expressions can get. I would definitely write a proper parser for it, since only then can I be confident to have done it properly. Plus, I will parse the string into an abstract syntax tree so that at the end I will automatically have a nicely modeled tree of objects:

```
class Node { ... }

class StringLiteral extends Node {
  public String getValue() { ... }
}

class Term extends Node {
  public String getName() { ... }
  public int getArity() { ... }
  public Node getArgument(int index) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But now how will you parse the string to get these nodes ??

Comment: The basic idea is to write a `Parser` class that has one method per syntactical element that you are interested in. I would call them `List<Node> parseArray()`, `Term parseTerm()`, `StringLiteral parseStringLiteral()`, `Node parseExpression()`. The implementation of `parseArray` would look roughly like `read('[']); while (next() != ']') { parseExpression(); } read(']');`. The methods basically contain sequences of these operations or large switch statements, which decide what to parse next, depending on the next character from the input.